# Deployment fails on google app engine with nuxt

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Im trying to deploy my vue/nuxt app on google app engine. I have been deploying it the same way for almost 2 years now and have 178 versions of it. Nothing has changed in the app.yaml file or within my GCP account but the deployment is now failing with Error [13]: an internal error occurred. I have tried NUMEROUS things, following multiple guides here on stackoverflow as well as github, and nothing works. While debugging, i noticed that it says ***'Operation [apps/myApp/operations/operationIdHere] not complete. Waiting to retry'*** over and over and over until it ultimately fails. Below are things Ive tried, any help is appreciated.

Things Ive tried to no avail:

- Changing the payment on file
- Logging into the CLI again
- Removing everything from the app.yaml file except 'runtime: nodejs14'
- Updating the gcloud cli
- Uninstalling and re-installing the gcloud CLI
- Updating node from 14.17.3 to 18+ and updating the runtime in the yaml file
- Running 'gcloud config set storage/use_gsutil true' in the command line
- Restarting the mac/vs code
- Changing wifi

Comment: Since you mentioned updating your gcloud CLI, you should note the [breaking change](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#April_11_2023) from April 11

Comment: @NoCommandLine Wow, that solved my issue. Not sure how I missed that breaking change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moving from comments to answer so it's clearer to others**

April 11, 2023 release introduced a [breaking change](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#April_11_2023) to Nodejs Apps

> For all the services using the Node.js runtime, npm run build now automatically runs during deployment if you have the npm build script defined in your package.json file.

The new design is that if you're using Node.js buildpacks and if your `package.json` has a `build` script, GAE will **automatically** run your build script during deployment. This means you must have every thing set up properly so that building of your App will work. The documentation also contains ways to have the build command skipped.